# Error during execution of trigger. How to rework select statement?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm relatively new to triggers so forgive me if this doesn't look how it should. I am creating a trigger that checks a user account for last payment date and sets a value to 0 if they haven't paid in a while. I created what I thought was a correct trigger but I get the error, "error during execution of trigger" when its triggered. From what I understand the select statement is causing the error as it selecting values which are in the process of being changed. Here is my code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t
  BEFORE 
   UPDATE OF LASTLOGINDATE
   ON USERS
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   USER_CHECK NUMBER;
   PAYMENTDATE_CHECK DATE;
   ISACTIVE_CHECK CHAR(1);

BEGIN 
   SELECT U.USERID, U.ISACTIVE, UP.PAYMENTDATE 
   INTO USER_CHECK, PAYMENTDATE_CHECK, ISACTIVE_CHECK
   FROM USERS U JOIN USERPAYMENTS UP ON U.USERID = UP.USERID
   WHERE UP.PAYMENTDATE < TRUNC(SYSDATE-60);

  IF ISACTIVE_CHECK = 1 THEN
    UPDATE USERS U
    SET ISACTIVE = 0
    WHERE U.USERID = USER_CHECK;

    INSERT INTO DEACTIVATEDUSERS
    VALUES(USER_CHECK,SYSDATE);

 END IF;


 END;
```

From what I thought, since the select is in the begin statement, it would run before an update, nothing would be changing about the tables until after if runs through the trigger. I tried but using :old in front of the select variables but that doesn't seem to be the right use.

And here is the update statement i was trying.

```
UPDATE USERS 
SET LASTLOGINDATE = SYSDATE
WHERE USERID = 5;
```

Comment: can there be more than one userpayment record per user?

Comment: Yes there could be. It's a record for every time a payment is made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues:

1. The `select` you do in the trigger sets the variable `isactive_check` to a payment date, and vice versa. There is an accidental switch there, which will have a negative effect on the next `if`;
2. The same `select` should return exactly one record, which by the looks of it is not guaranteed, since you join with table `userpayments`, which may have several payments for the selected user that meet the condition, or none at all. Change that `select` to do an aggregation.
3. If a user has more than one payment record, the condition might be true for one, but not for another. So if you are interested only in users who have not paid in a long while, such user should not be included, even though they have an old payment record. Instead you should check whether *all* records meet the condition. This you can do with a `having` clause.
4. As the table `users` is mutating (the update trigger is on that table), you cannot perform every action on that same table, as it would otherwise lead to a kind of deadlock. This means you need to rethink what the purpose is of the trigger. As this is about an update for a specific user, you actually don't need to check the whole table, but only the record that is being changed. For that you can use the special `new` variable.

I would suggest this SQL instead:

```
SELECT   MAX(UP.PAYMENTDATE)
INTO     PAYMENTDATE_CHECK
FROM     USERPAYMENTS
WHERE    USERID = :NEW.USERID
```

and then continue with the checks:

```
IF :NEW.ISACTIVE = 1 AND PAYMENTDATE_CHECK < TRUNC(SYSDATE-60) THEN
    :NEW.ISACTIVE := 0;

    INSERT INTO DEACTIVATEDUSERS (USER_ID, DEACTIVATION_DATE)
    VALUES(USER_CHECK,SYSDATE);

END IF;
```

Now you have avoided to do anything in the table `users` and have made the checks and modification via the `:new` "record".

Also, it is good practice to mention the column names in an `insert` statement, which I have done in above code (adapt column names as needed):

Make sure the trigger is compiled and produces no compilation errors.

Comment: So what you said makes sense. If I change the select it compiles with error, "SQL Statement ignored" and "ORA-00936: missing expression" and those don't seem to point to anything relevant.

Comment: Sorry, I had a dangling comma in that SQL. Deleted now.

Comment: Yep I saw that, it compiles but I'm still getting the error.*Cause:    A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
           this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
           in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
*Action:   Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.

Comment: Yes, there are limitations on what you can do with a table when you are in the middle of an update on the same table. I will make a suggestion in a minute... hold on. ;-)

Comment: No problem i appreciate the help.

Comment: OK, I made the update. I did not test this, so I hope it will work out.

Comment: So to confirm the :new actually references the users table? What is the usage of :old? It's still giving me an error after the :NEW.ISACTIVE = 0;
but I think with the :new I might be able to figure it out.

Comment: Yes, `:new` references the record that is about to be inserted into the table. It represents just one record (like a cursor), and has all the columns of the table. By altering a column value in `:new`, you actually do a kind of *just-in-time* fix, as Oracle will use the values of `:new` to complete the `insert` operation, after your trigger has completed. NB: there error is in the assignment: it must be `:=` instead of `=`. I fixed it now.